# Rotation about a point in OpenGL ES 2 (Android)

Tags: rotation, opengl-es2

I'm trying to implement rotation about a point (the origin) using quaternions. My camera is at `(0, 0, 3)`. I'm applying all the operations to the view matrix. Basically my rotation is at the moment not about the origin, but about the camera position. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public void rotate(float phi, float theta) {
        Quaternion phiRot = new Quaternion(0, 1, 0, (float)Math.toRadians(phi/2));
        Quaternion thetaRot = new Quaternion(1, 0, 0, (float)Math.toRadians(theta/2));

        Quaternion temp = thetaRot.mul(phiRot);

        camera.translate(0, 0, -3);
        camera.multiply(temp.toMatrix());
        camera.translate(0, 0, 3);
}
```

where

```
public void translate(float x, float y, float z) {
    Matrix.translateM(mViewMatrix, 0, x, y, z);
}

public void multiply(float[] matrix) {
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewMatrix, 0, matrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Solution that seems to work. Based off Milos' answer.

```
public void rotate(float phi, float theta) {
    Quaternion phiRot = new Quaternion(0, 1, 0, (float)Math.toRadians(phi/2));
    Quaternion thetaRot = new Quaternion(1, 0, 0, (float)Math.toRadians(theta/2));

    Quaternion temp = thetaRot.mul(phiRot);
    float[] rotate = temp.toMatrix();
    float transMinus[] = new float[16];
    float transPlus[] = new float[16];
    Matrix.setIdentityM(transMinus, 0);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(transPlus, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(transMinus, 0, 0, 0, -3);
    Matrix.translateM(transPlus, 0, 0, 0, 3);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(rotate, 0, transMinus, 0, rotate, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(rotate, 0, rotate, 0, transPlus, 0);

    camera.multiply(rotate);
}
```

Comment: What library are you using? What is the current behavior? Also, quaternions are *not* axis/angle representation, so likely the way you're initializing them will not do a hemispherical rotation as you're expecting...

Comment: No particular library - only [this](https://github.com/TraxNet/ShadingZen/blob/master/library/src/main/java/org/traxnet/shadingzen/math/Quaternion.java) class for quaternions. The current behaviour is described in the question: the camera at the moment, with the above code, moves along its position, not around the origin.

Maybe I don't get how quaternions work.

Comment: If you want to rotate about the origin, you shouldn't be translating your camera to the origin prior to rotating it. All rotations matrices rotate around the origin.

Comment: @Mokosha You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the translate function moves the camera in world coordinates, not in camera's own coordinate system.

You basically want to translate camera along it's forward vector by 3, rotate camera, then move back along the newly-rotated forward axis. Instead of doing the Matrix.translateM(...), try making a translation matrix along z axis, then (pre)multiplying it with camera rotation matrix. This *should* make it move along its forward vector properly and get you the wanted effect.

I used this way in achieving the similar thing in my game. Let me know if there's a better way.

Comment: Thanks very much, Milos! I think it worked, but I need to test it thoroughly. Could you please have a look at my code and point if there's anything that could be improved?

Comment: @user16547 Don't do that. It's not polite. Milos has answered your question, as it was titled by you. Give him the checkmark if he helped you fix your primary problem. Don't expect code reviews; this site is not for that. Please refer to the Help section.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm not too experienced with OpenGL ES 2, but doing it for a few weeks now, so I know that getting it to work can be frustrating sometimes. About the edited code, I would only recommend that you pre-allocate your float arrays outside of rotate function, so you don't take a new chunk of memory every time you call it (which is probably very often).

Comment: @NickWiggill No, I'm not doing _that_. My comment is written in plain English: "I think it worked, but I need to test it thoroughly." Why on Earth would I check an answer without testing it properly? 

Cheers, Milos!